# Making express endpoint async

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

Just creating a very simple endpoint with express to practice async/await .
This is my code:

```
    app.post('/products', async (req, res) =>  {
    try {
        console.log('req', req.body);
        const data = await addProduct(res.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);

    }
    catch(err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

When I try to start the server using the following command:

```
npx babel-node server.js --presets=es2015
```

I get:

```
    app.post('/products', async function (req, res) {
                      ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Any ideas?

Comment: async await as an ES7 feature, use [es2017 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/).

Comment: also don't use `res.body` but `req.body` (though it has nothing to do with async issues)

Comment: @Daniel, this solves the issue, but I now get SyntaxError: Unexpected token import, which I was no getting with es2015. import is not included in es2017 preset?

Comment: Ok, using both presets solve all the issues, I thought in es2017 was included everything from es2015, but apparently is not the case. Thanks!

Comment: @fgonzalez - yeah it's quite confusing but it only compiles ES7 to ES6 (written in the title). You'd get the same results using the [env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) which defaults to ES7 + ES6.

Comment: Do you mind to answer the question so I can accept it and close the question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async await as an ES7 feature, 2 options here:

1. Use [es2017 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/) along with your current ES6 preset
2. Use [env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) which defaults to ES7 + ES6 (recommended by babel)